# Push table rows to bottom with a fixed number of rows

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a question. I am currently using `.prepend()` which does push older table rows to the bottom while new table rows appear at the top. However, I have to restrict the number of table rows to 10, in doing so, once `.prepend()` reaches 10 rows, the latest row will appear at the bottom of the table and subsequently work it's way up again vice versa. I would like to know of a way that new rows will permanently appear at the top of the `<tbody>` while pushing the older rows to the bottom. Here are my codes for some reference.

```
// show the keys currently held in the specified type of storage in the

// specified table

 function showStorageKeys(type, table, table1) {

// get the specified type of storage, i.e. local or session
var storage = window[type + 'Storage'];
// remove the rows in the specified table before we start
$(table + " > tbody > tr").remove();
$(table1 + " > tbody > tr").remove();
// loop through the existing keys in the storage and add them to the TBODY
// element as rows
for (var i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
    var key = storage.key(i);
    if ((key == "0") || (key == "1") || (key == "2") || (key == "3") || (key == "4") ||             (key == "5") || (key == "6") ||
            (key == "7") || (key == "8") || (key == "9")) {
        var details = storage.getItem(key);
        details = details.split(";");
        var lat = details[0];
        var long = details[1];
        var zoom = details[2];
        var time = details[3];
        var address = details[4];
        //var date = details[5];
        if ((address == undefined) || (time == undefined) || (address == "")) {
            document.getElementById("dummy").value = "";
        }
 else {
            $("#history tbody").prepend(
"<tr>" + "<td width='5%'>" + time + "</td>"  +"<td>" + "<a href='JavaScript:getSite(" + lat + ',' + long + ',' + zoom + ")'>" + address +"</a>" +</td>" + "<td width='15%'>" + "<input type='submit'   value='Remove' onclick='removeItem(\"" + type + "\", \"" + key + "\")'/>" + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        }
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding an element to `#history tbody`, to ensure that this element has a maximum of 10 rows, I.e. a maximum of 10 children, you could do this:

```
while($("#history tbody").children().length > 10){
  $("#history tbody").children().last().remove()
}
```

And place this code directly after your code for inserting a new row.

Also, just to note, it is generally good practice to store the query object of elements in variables if they are used frequently as the call to the query function each time can be slow, so in the example I have given you above, and in your code, you should factor this out and it will be much faster:

```
var history_tbody = $("#history tbody")
...
history_tbody.prepend( ... )

while(history_tbody.children().length > 10){
  history_tbody.children().last().remove()
}
```

And try and make your definition of history_tbody happen only once, e.g. at the start of your file, after document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be to use [jQuery's `:gt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) like this:

```
$("#history tbody")
    .prepend('...')
    // using 9 here because gt() uses a zero-based index
    .find('tr:gt(9)').remove();
```